# Setting up a download limit for a computer

Tags: modem, bandwidth, resource-usage

A friend of me asked me a question like that

> I have a modem, and a house mate. He is using my modem, and slowing down my internet. What I want to do is, limit his bandwidth without using any program like netlimiter or so on his computer. How can I do that?

What are the ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flash the router with 3 party SW/FW http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index then it will support QoS

go to the page then to the Router Database, type in the name and se if it supports dd-wrt.
If it does your in luck dd-wrt is one of the best router sw you can use out there.

Comment: I didn't try it, but I will mark it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some routers support **QoS** which will allow you to limit or prioritize Internet bandwith to the various devices on the LAN.

Comment: Sure, but if his modem doesn't support it, he would have to replace it. And I doubt that a router that does QoS is cheap.

Comment: @Lo'oris: Well, that's where Tomato or DD-WRT comes in. They do QoS, and you don't need a fancy expensive router.

Comment: great, I didn't think about it